# Using FullCalendar Draggable on vue2.6 without npm

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

How would you use draggable with a CDN ?

I'm getting `Draggable is not defined`

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    events: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {}
  },
  methods: {
    setupDraggable(){
      var containerEl = document.getElementById('planned-tasks');
      new Draggable(containerEl, {
        itemSelector: '.fc-event',
        eventData: (eventEl) => {
          console.log(eventEl);
          return eventEl;
        }
      });
    }
  },
  mounted(){ this.setupDraggable();}
}
</script>
```

```
My CDN links :
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@6.1.6/index.global.min.js "></script>
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/daygrid@6.1.6/index.global.min.js "></script>
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/interaction@6.1.6/index.global.min.js "></script>
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/vue@6.1.6/dist/index.global.min.js "></script>
```

I tried this import Draggable from window.FullCalendar.Interaction.Draggable

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling the method on mount the libraries could not yet be loaded. Give it a try and call the function later on a button click to see it in action after everything is loaded.